# database design eloquent problem with query

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I need to create an app who manage soccer sheets

I have actually a table who store the match with both teams

```
match :
-id
-dt_math
-club_home_id
-club_visitor_id
```

each team have a sheet to create the list of players.

So what i did, i created table match_sheet to store the both sheets from the teams.

```
match_sheet :
-id
-match_id
```

to store the players in each sheets i created the table match_sheet_player

```
match_sheet_player:
-id
-match_sheet_id
-player_id
```

Now i need to display only the matchs who have the both sheets in my view. and i don't know how to achieve that.

The first query that i made is that :

```
  $matchs_sheets = MatchSheet::all();

    $matchs = Match::whereIn('id', $matchs_sheets->pluck('match_id'))->orderByDesc('dt_match')->paginate(5);
```

But this return my the match even if there is one sheet but not both sheets. i really need to show the match onyl if there is the two sheets.

Update :

here my data for math_sheet
 there is two records with 1659. 1659 is the id of the match. so i would like to only show match 1659 and not 1649 because there is only one record for this match
[image]

Comment: it returns me 3 results, one with match_id 2 and two others with match_id = 3 so i would like to display the match_id = 2 . hope it's understanable

Comment: you would like to display match_id = 2 or match_id = 3 with 2 sheets?

Comment: only match 3. i just updated the post with the real context of the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your model relationships are set up correctly, you can ask Laravel to get the matches only if the related model has a count of at least 2, using `has()`. For instance:

```
$matches = Match::whereIn('id', $ids)->has('matchSheet', '=', 2)...
```

Your relationship should be set up as e.g. this:

```
// on Match model
public function matchSheets()
{
    return $this->hasMany(MatchSheet::class);
}

// on MatchSheet model
public function match()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Match::class);
}
```

Docs here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many - I really recommend reading through them, they'll save you huge amounts of time eventually!

Comment: thanks for your answer, no i would like to have only the matches who have 2 sheets. and not only one. For exemple i have 3 sheets, two with match_id = 3 and one with match_id = 2 . i would like to display only the match id = 3 because this one with two sheet records with the id 3

Comment: I'm sorry. I really don't understand what you're after. Could you post some example data and expected results?

Comment: Oh, so the match_sheet_player table is irrelevant? You can just use `->has('match_sheet', '=', 2)` for that. I'll update my example, hang on.

Comment: how i need to configure the relation on match model with match_sheet ? because i have no forgein key on match who refer to match_sheet. only match_sheet to match

Comment: Added an example for that too.

Comment: You saved my day ! didn't know that i can do this, i will read carefully the doc !!! thanks again Joel for your help

Comment: No sweat, I'm glad it was helpful. :)